# append program's output to a file and display first n lines with a pipeline

Tags: linux, command-line, bash

What I'd like to do is to run a command, write all output to a file and display the first n lines.

in this example n=10

One solution I don't really like is:

```
./program > tempfile ; cat tempfile >> thefile ; head -n 10 tempfile
```

What I tried is

```
./program | tee -a thefile | head -n 10
```

However here the problem is, that ./program is terminated prematurely

Is there any trick without creating an intermediate temp file. 
(like a head command just displaying the first n lines, but continuing to read the rest silently)

One way to reproduce the issue with the pipeline and head is:

```
n=0 ; while [[ $n -lt 200 ]] ; do echo ======================== $n ; n=$((n + 1)) ; done | tee -a toto | head -n 3 ; echo "-" ; tail -n 200 toto
```

In fact for me the last line of file `toto` is random and varies but is almost never line 199.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/418896/how-to-redirect-output-to-a-file-and-stdout) might be of interest. Suggests that `./program 2>&1 | tee -a thefile | head -n 10` should work.

Comment: @Smock Just tried it out, even here program will be terminated prematurely. :-(

Comment: Are you saying that it gets terminated early because you are piping it?

Comment: Yes exactly, this seems to be the case. Just try following in a command line and you'll see:
`cat | head -n 3` and enter a few lines.

Funny that I use `head` for ages and I never noticed as in the use cases so far it didn't matter that the program terminated prematurly.

My suggested sed answer continues reading and doesn't terminate but it's not the most elegant

Comment: Ahhh - does the program read user input? I managed to replicate when I setup a script to read 10 vars in, and set head to show 5, it quit after 5 inputs. (it also mangled what got show on the terminal and what was recorded in the text file).#

Comment: It doesn't seem to be important whether user input is required or not.

I enhanced question with an example allowing to reproduce:
`n=0 ; while [[ $n -lt 200 ]] ; do echo ======================== $n ; n=$((n + 1)) ; done | tee -a toto | head -n 3 ; echo "-" ; tail -n 200 toto`

Comment: Well there's something going on that is complicating it as `man head | tee headfile.txt | head -n 10` works as I would expect. (But not `man ls` ... interesting)

Comment: Try `man rsync` I think `man head` is just too short. pipelines do have buffers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, answering my own question.

```
n=10
./program | tee -a thefile | sed -n "1,${n}p"
```

But perhaps there is something better?

Comment: ready to accept another answer if it shows up